# Covering two curves with the same endpoints with overlapping discs

Tags: complex-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

Let $\gamma_1, \gamma_2 : [0, 1] \to \mathbb{C}$ be curves where $\gamma_1(0) = \gamma_2(0)$ and $\gamma_1(1) = \gamma_2(1)$. Also suppose that
$$
\tag{$\star$}
\sup_{t \in [0, 1]}|\gamma_1(t) - \gamma_2(t)| < \varepsilon,
$$
for some fixed $\varepsilon > 0$. Prove that we can pick discs $D_0, \dots, D_n$ of radius $2\varepsilon$ that cover $\gamma_1 \cup \gamma_2$, as well as consecutive points $z_0, \dots, z_{n + 1} \in \gamma_1$ and $w_0, \dots, w_{n + 1} \in \gamma_2$ such that
$$
z_i, z_{i + 1}, w_i, w_{i + 1} \in D_i \quad \text{for all $1 \leq i \leq n$}.
$$
This is part of the proof of Theorem 5.1 in Stein and Shakarchi's *Complex Analysis* that the authors skimmed over. Here is the diagram from the book:

[image: figure 7]

#### My Attempt

For all $t \in [0, 1]$, let $B_t$ be the disc centered at $\gamma_1(t)$ of radius $\varepsilon$. By ($\star$), we have that $\gamma_2(t) \in B_t$. In total, the $B_t$'s cover $\gamma_1 \cup \gamma_2$, so by compactness, there is a finite subcovering. Write this subcovering as $B_{t_1}, \dots, B_{t_n}$ where the $t_i$'s are increasing. If $B_{t_i}$ always overlaps with $B_{t_{i + 1}}$, we would be able to expand each $B_{t_i}$ to be a disc of radius $2\varepsilon$, and we would be done. However, $B_{t_i}$ does not always overlap with $B_{t_{i + 1}}$. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I assume the discs $D_i$ must be of radius $< \epsilon$?

Comment: @TomKern Oops, thanks for catching that. The book specifies radius of $2\varepsilon$, but anything proportional to $\varepsilon$ should be fine. I updated the question.